# Placing fab icon atop CardView in android

Tags: android

I've a requirement where I want to set Floating button to act as add image button, in which I want my fab icon to be on bottom left of the card View (Which is parent of profile image), but the fab Icon is always sliding underneath cardview:

[image]

**My Layout xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:elevation="12dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_amf_memberProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="124dp"
        android:layout_height="124dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="60dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_amf_memberAvatar"
            android:contentDescription="Member Profile Picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_member" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_addImage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_add_new_member" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try using famelayout thats the easiest to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace LinearLayout with RelativeLayout
and set the right and below property

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:elevation="12dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_amf_memberProfilePic"
                android:layout_width="124dp"
                android:layout_height="124dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="60dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_amf_memberAvatar"
                    android:contentDescription="Member Profile Picture"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_sun" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_addImage"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_add_new_member" 
                android:layout_below="@id/cv_amf_memberProfilePic"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/cv_amf_memberProfilePic"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I had to add this `android:layout_marginTop="-43dp"`, then your solution worked. as I'm setting fab_icon height & width as `wrap_content`